# Cant create play 2 template in intellij : java play framework

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to java play 2 framework in IntelliJ, I can run the server without any issue. But I can't create a new play 2 templates. Can someone tell me what's the issue here?

I searched in [jetbrains support page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMXwq.png).

It says the issue is with intellij ide, but I tried the same thing with the latest version 2017.3, and the same issue prevails

click here:
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMXwq.png)

click here:
[But how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLafT.png)

[Note: I am following these video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYPFxrXyK0Bx9SBkNhJr1e2-NlIq4E7ED)

Comment: i was using play 2.6, which was the latest version, but latter i changed to version 2.5 where i could fix one issue.THE PROBLEM IS; the IDE doesn't gives any option to create PLAY 2 TEMPLATE.the issue is discussed in this page (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205998049-Subfolder-in-views-play-framework-not-see-templates- )

Comment: OK GREAT, i got the solution for my issue, it would be useful for other beginners:  INTELLIJ COMMUNITY EDITION DOESN'T GIVE THE OPTION TO CREATE THE PLAY 2 TEMPLATE (IF YOUR A STUDENT YOU CAN PURCHASE THE STUDENT LICENSE FOR FREE AND GET THAT OPTION), or else you can do the following in the community edition: select file from options and enter filename with .scala.html extension. for example you want to create index file, then you have to select file option and enter index.scala.html file name and then click on create file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK GREAT, i got the solution for my issue, it would be useful for other beginners: INTELLIJ COMMUNITY EDITION DOESN'T GIVE THE OPTION TO CREATE THE PLAY 2 TEMPLATE (IF YOUR A STUDENT YOU CAN PURCHASE THE STUDENT LICENSE FOR FREE AND GET THAT OPTION), or else you can do the following in the community edition: select file from options and enter filename with .scala.html extension. for example you want to create index file, then you have to select file option and enter index.scala.html file name and then click on create file – Mohamed Sajjadh Dec 29 '17 at 8:56

Comment: one more think I want to add is that do not forget to use sbt clean compile from terminal so that it will create template file of your  index.scala.html page in target->twirl->main->view.html directory